# Why does this array of floats give an error?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails-3

I have defined the following array:

```
m_curve = [1.32, 1.33, 1.34, 1.35, 1.36, 1.37, 1.38, 1.39, 1.40, 1.41, 1.42]
```

And when I assign it, such as follows:

```
a = m_curve[0][0]
```

I get the error:

```
undefined method `[]' for 1.32:Float
```

Am I creating the array of floats incorrectly?

Comment: Your array is one-dimensional. ruby can't figure out where to pull the second dimension from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're only creating a 1-dimensional array, yet you're referring to a 2-dimensional one.